# Having a hard time figuring out algorithm for non-intersecting paths

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

[image: multiple wires]

Like picture, I am given a starting point and an ending point for each wires(lines) in the (x,y) grid (it could be many many more wires that I have to find paths.) What I need to do is to find minimum paths of each wires that it doesn't intersect each other(if no possible solution found then its an exception.) 
I can find all possible paths from a point to an end of a single wire, but having hard time to think about multiple paths.

```
public static PriorityQueue<Path> pathesOfAWire(Chip chip, Wire w) {
    boolean[][] isVisited = new boolean[chip.dim.width][chip.dim.height];
    Path path = new Path(w);
    PriorityQueue<Path> ans = new PriorityQueue<>((x, y) -> x.length() - 
y.length());
    addAllPathesUtil(chip, w.from, w.to, isVisited, path, ans);
    return ans;
}

private static void addAllPathesUtil(Chip chip, Coord from, Coord to,
                                     boolean[][] isVisited, Path p,
                                     PriorityQueue<Path> ans) {
    isVisited[from.x][from.y] = true;
    if (from.equals(to)) {
        Path np = new Path(p.wire);
        for (int i = 1; i < p.length(); i++)
            np.add(p.get(i));
        ans.offer(np);
    }
    for (Coord neighbors : from.neighbors(chip.dim)) {
        if (!isVisited[neighbors.x][neighbors.y] &&
                (chip.isFree(neighbors) || neighbors.equals(to))) {
            p.add(neighbors);
            addAllPathesUtil(chip, neighbors, to, isVisited, p, ans);
            p.remove(neighbors);
        }
    }
    isVisited[from.x][from.y] = false;
}
```

This is my code for only one path(one starting point and an ending point.)

```
public static void helper(Chip chip, Coord[] from, Coord[] to,
                          boolean[][] isVisited, Path[] p,
                          Map<Integer, Path> ans) {
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        isVisited[from[i].x][from[i].y] = true;
    }
    boolean completed = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        if (!from[i].equals(to[i])) {
            completed = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Wire " + (i + 1) + " : " + p[i]);
    }
    if (completed) {
        System.out.println("hihihi");
        for (Path a : p) {
            Path np = new Path(a.wire);
            for (int i = 1; i < a.length(); i++)
                np.add(a.get(i));
            ans.put(np.wire.wireId, np);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        for (Coord neighbors : from[i].neighbors(chip.dim)) {
            if (!isVisited[neighbors.x][neighbors.y] &&
                    (chip.isFree(neighbors) || neighbors.equals(to[i]))) {
                p[i].add(neighbors);
                from[i] = neighbors;
                helper(chip, from, to, isVisited, p, ans);
                p[i].remove(neighbors);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        isVisited[from[i].x][from[i].y] = false;
    }
}
```

And with the algorithm for a single wire above in mind, I tried to apply the same logic for multiple wires, but failing to do it. I need help to improve my algorithm or some hint how to approach this problem in different way.
Chip is the grid that has obstacles and information of wires and free cells.
Map is an association between Integer(ID of wire) and a path
Thanks

Comment: This is the [PCB routing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)), which is not an easy problem to solve.